# JMeter Slave Reporting in Distributed Testing

Tags: jmeter

I am performing distributed testing using JMeter and getting collective result of all slaves on Master JMeter GUI.

Please let me know if it is possible to capture separate reports for each slave?

For example, I have configured 2 Slaves + 1 Master JMeter. On executing the test, I would like capture separate report of each slave.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get per-slave results as follows:

1. Add a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) or your choice to Test Plan
2. Specify `Filename` in "Write results to file" section and choose what you need to store via "Configure" button
3. Once test finishes you'll have to collect result files from slave machines

Be aware that:

- By default not everything can be stored, i.e. response data is being removed form successful samples
- Listeners have their cost. See [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) to get an idea regarding impact and why it is better to have them off during load test.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, don't use distributed testing, just launch 1 separate JMeter per slave machine.