# Jmeter- distributed testing, save separate results for each slave

Tags: jmeter

I have 1 master and 2 slave machines setup. I want to create two separate summary report, one for each slave.

I know the question in duplicate of this question, but the solution provide does not work for me.

[JMeter Slave Reporting in Distributed Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383616/jmeter-slave-reporting-in-distributed-testing)

In my test plan I have summary report and have added "filename"(or complete path) under write results to file.
When I execute my test plan, result file is saved in master system with combined results of both the slaves. How can I get the response times of the requests executed with each slaves separately?

Comment: You can run each slave as a master of it own

Answer (score 1):

If you add a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) to your Test Plan and configure it to save results into a file it will create a results file on **each** slave machine so once your test is done you will be able to fetch these results file from **slaves** and perform required analysis.

Assuming your configuration is good you should have 1 cumulative result on master and 2 separate results on each slaves.

Another option is using [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function as a sampler label prefix (or postfix) so you will be able to distinguish samplers coming from different slaves in the main .jtl results file. This approach will allow you to avoid unnecessary disk IO overhead during test execution required to generate an extra file with the results.

Once you test finishes you will be able to split main .jtl results file using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to generate separate results files per slave basing on slave machine hostname or IP address.

You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Filter Results TOol]